# Django and celery on different servers and celery being able to send a callback to django once a task gets completed

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I have a django project where I am using celery with rabbitmq to perform a set of async. tasks. So the setup i have planned goes like this.

1. Django app running on one server.
2. Celery workers and rabbitmq running from another server.

My initial issue being, how to do i access django models from the celery tasks resting on another server?

and assuming I am not able to access the Django models, is there a way once the tasks gets completed, i can send a callback to the Django application passing values, so that i get to update the Django's database based on the values passed?

Answer (score 7):

Concerning your first question, accessing django models from the workers' server:

Your django app must be available on both **Server A** (serving users) and **Server B** (hosting the celery workers)

Concerning your second question, updating the database based on the values. Do you mean the result of the async task? If so, then you have two options:

- You can just save whatever you need to save from within the task itself, assuming you have access to the database.
- You could use a results backend (one of which is through the Django ORM) as mentioned in the official documentation of Celery about [Keeping Results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results)

Comment: Your second solution to my second question, doesnt using a result backend and fetching the returned result from the task make the whole process  synchronous one, is there a way to do it asyncronously??

Comment: it's not synchronous because you don't have to wait while the task runs. Of course you can fetch the results only when they are ready, but that doesn't make it a synchronous process.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following set up on my application:

1. Task is initiated from Django - information is extracted from the model instance and passed to the task as a dictionary. NB - this will be more future proof as Celery 4 will default to JSON encoding
2. Remote server runs task and creates a dictionary of results
3. Remote server then calls an update task that is only listened for by a worker on the Django server.
4. Django worker read results dictionary and updates model.

The Django worker listens to a separate queue, those this isn't strictly necessary. Results backend isn't used - data needed is just passed to the task